# how to fetch two models in same controller in same function

Tags: node.js, mongoose, model

i've fetch data of single model from the database but i'm getting problem while fetching multiple model from the database. while fetching model everything related to model comes in return but i want only id and datas
this is my code

```
router.get('/',(req,res) =>{
    const how = Howitworks.find().lean();
    const value = Slider.find().lean();
    console.log(how)
    res.render('index', {how: how, value: value});
})
```

this is my code for fetching single model

```
router.get('/',(req,res) =>{
    
    Howitworks.find((err,docs)=>{
        
        if(!err){
            
            res.render("index",{
                list:docs

            })
        }
        else {
            console.log("error in retriving hoiw it works list: "+err)
        }
    }).lean()
})
```

is there any way to fetch both model?

Comment: show you data from mongoose please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi As I understood your code, your script should be like below.

```
router.get('/', async(req,res) =>{
    const how = await Howitworks.find().lean();
    const value = await Slider.find().lean();
    //  You can process how, values here and use then
    console.log(how)
    res.render('index', {how: how, value: value});
})
```